# Erro in setting jenkins with sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

In setting jenkins with sonarqube i am getting the following error

```
FATAL: Unable to find SonarQube project settings at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sonar_job\sonar_job
ERROR: Unable to find SonarQube project settings at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sonar_job\sonar_job
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: > git.exe rev-list --no-walk 2bfe31fcd6577b86a0490710fdf1cef3b129d724 # timeout=10
FATAL: Unable to find SonarQube project settings at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sonar_job\sonar_job
ERROR: Unable to find SonarQube project settings at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sonar_job\sonar_job
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Please follow [these](https://medium.com/@amitvermaa93/jenkins-sonarqube-integration-129f5c49c4ca) instructions.